# Which compression to use between embedded processors (known byte distributions)

Tags: c, embedded, compression

I'm working with radio-to-radio communications where bandwidth is really really precious. It's all done with on the metal C code (no OS, small atmel 8bit microprocessors). So the idea of compression becomes appealing for some large, but rare, transmissions.

I'm no compression expert. I've used the command line tools to shrink files and looked at how much I get. And linked a library or two over the years. But never anything this low level.

In one example, I want to move about 28K over the air between processors. If I just do a simple bzip2 -9 on a representative file, I get about 65% of the original size.

But I'm curious if I can do better though. I am (naively?) under the impression that most basic compression formats must be some declaration of metadata up front, that describes how to inflate a bitstream that follows. What I don't know is how much space that metadata itself takes up. I histogram'ed said same file, and a number of other ones, and found that due to the nature of what's being transmitted, the histogram is almost always about the same. So I'm curious if I could hard code these frequencies in my code so that that was no longer dynamic, but also wasn't transmitted as part of the packet.

For example, my understanding of a huffman encoding is that usually there's a "dictionary" up front, followed by a bitstream. And that if a compressor does it by blocks, each block will have its own dictionary.

On top of this, it's a small processor, with a small footprint, I'd like to keep whatever I do small, simple, and straightforward.

So I guess the basic question is, what, if any, basic compression algorithm would you implement in this kind of environment/scenario. Especially taking into account, that you can basically precompile a representative histogram of the bytes per transmission.

Comment: Bzip has no knowledge of your data, so it has to treat every byte as precious.  With your knowledge of the actual value of your data stream, you can make choices on what to keep at a high fidelity and what can be done at a lower fidelity.  This is how you get better-than-lossless compression in JPEG, MP3, or a GSM codec - throw away or spend less bits on unimportant stuff.

Comment: I still need to be lossless for my application.

Comment: If you need lossless, then your suggestion makes sense - get a sample of data frequencies and Huffman encode them.  Are you really sending bytes or is the data grouped in some way?  Might make sense to encode based on 2 or 4 bytes instead.  To keep it manageable, encode the most common 256 4 byte groupings, then use the least common byte to signal between encoded or unencoded data.

Comment: Each packet is about 110 bytes. It's a zigbee variant.

Comment: [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel–Ziv–Welch) does an adaptive compression, negating the need for a true up-front dictionary.  Unfortunately it does not take advantage of a prior known distribution.  In theory, you can get a better compression using a Huffman encoding and crafting your own algorithm, but at the end-of-the day, using well known and optimized algorithm are going to be difficult to significantly beat.  Code may realize a significant saving using the _history_ of previous messages.

Comment: If your histogram is really that close between packets, maybe you could capture a "default" packet and only send the diffs?  Dumb Q, are you sending binary data or ASCII data? (ie, sprintf into a string, and sending the string?)

Comment: You should take a look at what this lovely gentleman has to say about [Huffman Trees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umTbivyJoiI)

Comment: The packets are binary data. They're over the air firmware updates.

Comment: Make sure you have the maximum packet size correct - I know for the XBee modules the largest payload is a lot less than 110 bytes.

Comment: Arithmetic coding is always as good as Huffman; when the distribution is composed of sums of 2^-n, then Huffman is also the optimal. Depending on the distribution, changing the coding scheme should buy you a few bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are suggesting, providing preset frequency data, would help very little.  Or more likely it would hurt, since you will take a hit by not using optimal codes.  As an example, only about 80 bytes at the start of a deflate block is needed to represent the literal/length and distance Huffman codes.  A slight increase in the, say, 18 KB of your compressed data could easily cancel that.

With [zlib](http://zlib.net/), you could use a representative one of your 28K messages as a dictionary in which to search for matching strings.  This could help the compression quite a bit, if there are many common strings in your messages.  See `deflateSetDictionary()` and `inflateSetDictionary()`.